# Add source code as a library in Xcode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, linker

I've got some source code (.h and .m files) that being developed by someone else.

I need to add it to my project as a (static) library Or even to add it as a source files that to be used by my own source files..

When I copy and past the folder containing the .m and .h files into my project I got a link error.

How to do that?

Comment: What is the error? What solutions have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this tutorial will help you:

[**Using static libraries with Xcode**](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/xcode-static-libraries/)